# Error: EntitySet 'Building' that was specified in page markup does not exist on the Container

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've setup an ItemTeplate like so in a GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Building">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label 
            ID="lblBuilding" 
            Text='<%# Bind("Building1.building_name") %>' 
            runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:EntityDataSource 
            ID="EditHousingDataSource" 
            runat="server" 
            EnableDelete="true" 
            ConnectionString="name=pbu_housingEntities"
            DefaultContainerName="pbu_housingEntities" 
            EnableFlattening="false" 
            EntitySetName="Building" 
            EntityTypeFilter="Building" />
        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="ddlBuilding" 
            runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="EditHousingDataSource"
            DataTextField="building_name" 
            DataValueField="ID" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm receiving the error:

> EntitySet 'Building' that was specified in page markup does not exist on the Container.

Any ideas on why? There is definitely a Building entity in the pbu_housingEntities?

Comment: Did you recently add the Building EntitySet to the solution?  Are there other pages or controls that successfully reference the Building EntitySet?  Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution to ensure the aspx has an updated file reference (if the project is referenced, then your Intellisense would still show the EntitySet, even if its not in the referenced dll)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here ...

```
EntitySetName="Building"
```

... you don't have to specify the class name of your entity but the name of the `ObjectSet<Building>` property of your derived ObjectContext.

This might be called `Buildings`. You can check this in your edmx model configuration or in the generated file for your derived ObjectContext.